# Can I have a different texture folder for a given material?

Tags: texturing, materials, scripting

I have a workflow where a set of about 10 textures are generated at different resolutions, these are then collected into folders named e.g. 1000 for the 1000 DPI assets. The texture names follow a strict convention, so the texture `1000/asset_a.png` corresponds exactly (other than resolution) to `2000/asset_a.png`, for example. These textures are referenced in texture nodes in a material. I'd like to be able to set the texture path base folder for just that material so I can easily switch between different texture sets.

As it stands I have to go into each texture node and manually edit the path to point at the correct folder.

If there was a way to set a path in the scene which I could reference in the texture relative path, that would be ideal, but I can't find any such feature.

Other materials are using textures from the standard texture base folder so I can't just point the file path for textures somewhere else.

Has anyone managed this? Or can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: There are two ways: change texture paths using script, or make a node, that switch between two image textures

Comment: Some other ideas: folder [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), using relative paths and moving the .blend file, just renaming the folders before opening the .blend file.

Comment: Another no-coding workaround. Keep all of said materials as a library each in its own individual file, linked from the "main scene" file. You can then go to *File > External Data* and relocate all said textures to a different folder path. After this step you may even append said material back into the main file, if maintaining multiple libraries is a hassle.

Comment: You can do it with the script in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182986/upgrading-an-old-python-script-change-all-image-paths-at-once)

Comment: Some comments for the mod who closed this question:
1 - The linked question involves Python programming which may be out of scope for many
2 - That question is about changing _all_ texture paths, rather than the paths associated with a specific material

So... yeah, not  great, but thanks for closing it for me.

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck you can [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/238742/edit) your question and explain why Python solution is invalid. You mentioned in your question declaring a *global string*, which I think implies strongly a Python solution.

Comment: I just meant global as in available to the shader editor even if defined in the scene somehow, perhaps the wording wasn't good - anyway, if it's Python, it's Python, which I really wanted to avoid

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variation of a script like the one from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186192/is-there-an-easy-way-in-python-to-find-the-bpy-data-images-that-are-used-in-a-no/204950#204950)

```py
import bpy

# The path which should be replaced
oldpath = "C:\\OLDpath\\"

# The new path which replaces the old one
newpath = "D:\\NewPth\\"

image_count = 0

for image in bpy.data.images:
    if not image.filepath.startswith(oldpath):
        continue
    image.filepath = image.filepath.replace(oldpath, newpath)
    image.reload()
    image_count += 1
```

You could add some logic to ask for the two paths so that you don't have to edit the script each time.  It might even make a nice add-on.

Comment: fyi I wrote an add-on to do this in a more user friendly way for non Python people. Available here: https://github.com/cskilbeck/bl_TextureLocator